# How can I add more icon in input tag when I key down comma

Tags: javascript, html, input, icons, markup

I'm wondering how can I add more icon, when I keydown comma inside input tag

[before input comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoLCE.png) 
[after input comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8vfS.png)

is there any plugins or reference code? please let me know

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an EventListener for the `keyup` event, that is fired, if a key was pressed and is released. The event interface proviedes a `code` property, that contains the code of the key that was pressed. If this `code` is "Comma", you add a  (or any other character or icon) to the input's value:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  if (event.code === "Comma")
    input.value += "";
})
```

```html
<input type="text" value="">
```

If you want to insert material icons, you can use a `div` with `contenteditable` and insert a `<span class="material-icons">[icon-name]</span>` after the user typed a comma:

```js
const icon = `<span class="material-icons">house</span>`

const input = document.querySelector("div[contenteditable]");

input.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  if (event.code === "Comma")
    input.innerHTML += icon;
})
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div contenteditable><span class="material-icons">house</span></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The bad thing about this is, that for example every house icon is five characters long, because we use `house` in the span and that is a house icon in the google material icons font, but it still remains five characters long. But this could be solved using another icon font, that works with classes.

Comment: Oh... I mean, I want to add icons embeded from google Icons like <span class="material-icons>icon</span>, not emoji. 

 hmm.. How can I add input's value HTML tags? 
anyway, I appreciate your kindness answer.

Comment: I added a solution to accomplish this, but it is not really nice. Does it solve your problem?